# How to construct a callable from a Python code object?

Tags: python-3.x

*Realize this is a rather obscure question, so I'll explain why I'm looking into this.*

A Python jit compiler takes a callable and returns a callable.

This is fine, however - the API I'm currently working with uses a Python code object.

A simplistic answer to this question would be to write a function to execute the code, eg:

```
def code_to_function(code):
    def fn():
        return eval(code)
    return fn

# example use
code  = compile("1 + 1", '<string>', 'eval')
fn = code_to_function(code)
print(fn())  # --> 2
```

Which is correct, but in this case the jit (happens to be numba), won't evaluate the actual number crunching parts - which is needed to be useful.

So the question is, how to take a code object which evaluates to a value, and convert/construct a callable from it?

---

Update, thanks to @jsbueno's answer, [here's an example of a simple expression evaluator using numba](https://gist.github.com/ideasman42/c9ef91230ac67de6572f).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from types import FunctionType

new_function = FunctionType(code,  globals[, name[, argdefs[, closure]]])
```

The remaining parameters above may be taken from the original function you have.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit, @jsbueno answer is better, but this may be a useful alternative, or at least be interesting for Python developers interested in manipulating functions.*

---

This can be done by replacing a functions `__code__`, attrubute, eg:

```
def code_to_function(code):
    def fn_dummy():
        return None

    fn_dummy.__code__ = code
    return fn_dummy


# example use
code  = compile("1 + 1", '<string>', 'eval')
fn = code_to_function(code)
print(fn())  # --> 2
```